# UnhandledException during checking internet connection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to check internet connection in App.xaml.cs file but when I'm doing it in constructor it throws UnhandledException, why? Is it possible to do this? When I check it in for example MainPage.xaml.cs it works.

My code:

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connected.");
}
```

Call Stack:

```
App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e)
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.IsNonRecoverableUserException(System.Exception ex, out uint xresultValue)
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
     System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority)
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context)
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args)
    System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pParams, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pResult)
```

Comment: Show the error you getting !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should avoid calling **Message-box** during Application launching or initializing. Sometimes It would give you error as:

**"Error displaying MessageBox. The most common reason is attempting to call Show while an application is launching or being activated. Wait for page navigation events before calling Show."**

You can use **Debug.WriteLine("Connected.");** instead **MessageBox.Show("Connected.");**

Other thing is that if this is not working check for the **capabilities** that you have given or not for accessing internet Connection.

IF i am using your code as :

```
    if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Connected.");
    }
```

Its working fine.

Comment: Your welcome. so mark as answered for future Reference for Others.

Answer (score 0):

You should surround your displayed code in a try-catch block

eg:

```
try
{
  if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Connected.");
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

this is a pretty crude exception handling, you can read more on it here http://www.dotnetperls.com/exception

Comment: I still don't get any MessageBox even with exception. Is it possible to check connection in App.xaml.cs constructor?